# Can't set SPS-Department property

Tags: 2013, user-profile, taxonomy

I've written a timer job with C# that sets some user properties, including SPS-Department which is bound to a Term Set. Job works perfect on dev machine. On product machine it fails with exception:

> Exception caught for user domain\user. Message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index. Stack:     at
>   System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileValueCollectionBase.AddTaxonomyTerm(Term
>   term) at
>   ADUpdater.Code.ColvirToUserProfileUpdater.UpdateUserProfilesFromColvir(String
>   connectionString, String webAppUrl)

My code looks like this:

```
    ...
var prop = userProfile[PropertyConstants.SPSDepartment];
UserProfileConfigManager upcManager = new UserProfileConfigManager(serviceCtx);
ProfilePropertyManager propManager = upcManager.ProfilePropertyManager;
CorePropertyManager corePropertyManager = profileManager.GetCoreProperties();
CoreProperty property = corePropertyManager.GetPropertyByName(PropertyConstants.SPSDepartment);
TermSet ts = property.TermSet;
if (userDepGuid != Guid.Empty)
{
    prop.Clear();
    var newValue = ts.GetTerm(userDepGuid);
    prop.AddTaxonomyTerm(newValue);
}
...
userProfile.Commit();
```

`userDepGuid` is not null, `newValue` also is not null. I'm stuck. Some fresh ideas might be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the profile of user exists?

Comment: @Amit yes is does

Comment: Is it running under an account that has permission to modify the user's profile?

Comment: @EricAlexander yes it runs under farm admin account

Comment: Is it an Open or Closed Term Set?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott It is Open Term Set

Answer (score 0):

replace **prop.clear()** with **prop.Value=null;**

```
if (userDepGuid != Guid.Empty)
    {
        //prop.Clear();
       prop.Value=null;
        var newValue = ts.GetTerm(userDepGuid);
        prop.AddTaxonomyTerm(newValue);
    }
```